# avoid two iterations through list

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-objects

I have a generic list, which I use linq to search like so:

```
NotificationWindowItem item = itemList.Where(elm => elm.UID == UID).SingleOrDefault();
itemList.Where(elm => elm.UID == UID).SingleOrDefault().Read = true;
```

I then go on to call a WCF web service with values from `item`.
I do this since it is my understanding that SingleOrDefault() returns a new IEnumerable, with copies of the objects. (Did I misunderstand?)
The list is usually not very long, so the extra iteration is not very significant, but it really bugs me.

I just can't think of a way to consolidate the two iterations.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use item.Read = true ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SingleOrDefault` does not return an IEnumerable but a single item instead. Since you already assign and keep it in your variable `item`, why not simply use that for further processing?

```
NotificationWindowItem item = itemList.Where(elm => elm.UID == UID).SingleOrDefault();
item.Read = true;
```

You can further simplify this. And, as pointed out by Tim, you need a null check (see below why):

```
NotificationWindowItem item = itemList.SingleOrDefault(elm => elm.UID == UID);
if (item == null)
{
    // ... some alternative or error handling code
}
else
{
    item.Read = true;
}
```

To expand on your questions/unclarities:

1. itemList is a list of item. Each item is a NotificationWindowItem. The list implements the IEnumerable interface. (More precisely, I am assuming that itemList is a `List<NotificationWindowItem>` which implements `IEnumerable<NotificationWindowItem>`.
2. Where is an extension method that takes the `IEnumerable<NotificationWindowItem>` and creates another `IEnumerable<NotificationWindowItem>` that only contains matching elements.
3. SingleOrDefault takes an `IEnumerable<NotificationWindowItem>` and returns a normal, simple, single NotificationWindowItem. (More than that, it verifies that there only is a single matching element. If more than one element match it would throw an exception. If no element matches, it returns `default(T)` which is `null` in your case).
4. `item` is *not* an `IEnumerable`. It is a `NotificationWindowItem`. There is no magic behind. It is a simple object. It does not have anyhting to do with LINQ. You only used LINQ to retrieve it, but afterwards you can do anything you could do with any other instance of NotificationWindowItem.

Comment: You might want to add a null-check in case there's no  NotificationWindowItem  with the given UID.

Comment: So the item is passed by ref? I was under the impression that this extension method made a copy of the object. Then it is simpler than I thought :)

Comment: @EladLachmi It's not that the item is passed by reference, the item itself *is a* reference (because it's a class) so copying it by value is only making another copy of the reference.

Comment: @chiccodoro: +1 side note: point 3 should end with _"returns a **single** NotificationWindowItem"_. You may also want to mention that `SingleOrdefault` throws an exception if there's more than one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this - no double loops required.

```
var item = itemList.SingleOrDefault(elm => elm.UID == UID);
item.Read = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
NotificationWindowItem item = itemList.Where(elm => elm.UID == UID).SingleOrDefault().toList();
```

to resolve your problem.